# Can't delete a folder that I created

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

Due to some unrelated issues with OneDrive, I need to delete my Music folder. I tried just deleting it, but I keep getting an "Access Denied" error, even though I'm an administrator, and I created the folder. The message says I need to get permission from myself. I have tried deleting it using an elevated prompt, and that doesn't work either. I get the same "Access Denied" message every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively use `ICALCS` to reset files permissions: :

1. Press windows key + X and choose (Command Prompt Admin) or Run `cmd` as Administrator
2. Select target folder
3. To reset all the files permissions, type:

   `icacls * /T /Q /C /RESET`

After that, the files permissions will be reset and you can delete the folder

Comment: tried this, got "Access is denied"

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder, go to Properties then the Security tab.

Click Edit then select your current user name and make sure the "Full Control" is selected.  If it is not, click it.  You may be asked for administrator confirmation.

Click OK then close everything.

You should now be able to delete the folder.